# C# -> C DLL callback crash after first (successful) iteration

Tags: c#, callback, marshalling, dllimport, unmanaged

My C# calls a C++DLL in order to obtain data from a device. Data are returned through a callback function which has a window handle as input and one integer and two structs as by ref input values.

When the callback is triggered, the DLL is supposed to return 5 records, i.e. to be triggered 5 times. The first record arrives with all proper values but then the app crashes (0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000), so my guess is that it crashes right before sending the second set of data.

I don’t have access to the source code of the DLL but I have access to the C++ app that demonstrates its usage.

This is how I declare the delegate and import the function that contains the callback as a member:

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private  delegate void onGetParaminfoHandler( IntPtr handle, ref int hIndex, ref PATINFO pi, ref PARAMINFO pri);

    private static onGetParaminfoHandler ogp; //--declaration reference of the callback to be used

    [DllImport("DataTraffic.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void StartUpLoad(IntPtr handle, onGetParaminfoHandler myCallback);
```

Here’s the declaration of the two structs, PATINFO and PARAMINFO:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]        
    public struct PATINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        string szDeviceInfo;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        string szUserName;//name
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        string szTime;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        uint nID;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        uint nGender;//Sex 1 = male 0: Female
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        uint nStandard;//Standard 1:ers 2:knudson 3:usa 4: Other
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        uint nAge;//Age
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        uint nHeight;//Height cm
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        uint nWeight;//weight kg
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        bool BBDT;//whether relaxing True=Diastolic
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        bool bSmoker;//Smoking true= Smoking          
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public  struct PARAMINFO
    {
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fffvc;//Maximum force capacity
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFEV1;//a second amount
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fPEF;//Peak flow rate
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFEV1Per;//FEV1/FVC
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFEF25;//25% capacity
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFEF750;//50% capacity
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFEF75;//75% capacity
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFEF2575;//25-75% capacity
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fFET;//exhalation Time
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fEVOL;//Extrapolation Volume
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fEOTV;//End of test volume
        //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R4)]
        float fPEFT;//Peak Time        
    };
```

Here’s how I call the callback function:

```
public  static void StartDataupload(IntPtr handle)
    {                                       
       ogp = new onGetParaminfoHandler(GetParaminfo); //--keep reference of the delegate
       GC.KeepAlive(ogp); //-- not much help from this one
       StartUpLoad(handle, ogp);                       
    }
```

And the callback itself:

```
private static void GetParaminfo(IntPtr handle, ref int hIndex,ref PATINFO pi, ref PARAMINFO pri)
   {            enter code here
         if (hIndex >= 1)
           {
               PATINFO pat = new PATINFO();
               pat = pi;
               PARAMINFO par = new PARAMINFO();
               par = pri;                

               int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
               if (error != 0)
               throw new Win32Exception(error);
           }
```

Some more info: the LastWin32Error returns large, random numbers which of course translate to Unknown errors. I suspect that between the first and the second call of the callback by the DLL, some pointer gets lost and so do I.

Here’s how the sample code (which works fine) in C calls the callback:

```
StartUpLoad(GetSafeHwnd(), GetParamInfo);
```

And **part** of the callback function of the sample C program which also uses the same DLL:

```
 static void GetParamInfo(HWND hWnd, int &nIndex, PATINFO &PatientInf, PARAMINFO &ParamInf)
{
    if(nIndex >= 1)
    {
        PATINFO *pPatientInf = new PATINFO;
        PARAMINFO *pParamInf = new PARAMINFO;

        *pPatientInf = PatientInf;
        *pParamInf = ParamInf;

        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_RECEIVEONECASE, 
                    reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(pPatientInf), 
                    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(pParamInf));
    } 
    else if(nIndex == FLAG_UPLOAD_STOP)
    {
        EnableOk(hWnd);
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_RECEIVECOMPLETE, PatientInf.nID, 0);
    }
```

Any hints as to where to focus, would be greatly appreciated.

***edit***: here is the dllexport function signature:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void StartUpLoad(HWND hwnd, void (*pVoid)(HWND hWnd, int &nIndex, PATINFO &PatientInf, PARAMINFO &ParamInf));
```

and here are the definitions in C for the two structures:

```
typedef struct PATINFO 
{
    char szDeviceInfo[20];
    char szUserName[20];
    char szTime[20];
    UINT nID;
    UINT nGender;
    UINT nStandard;
    UINT nAge;
    UINT nHeight;
    UINT nWeight;
    BOOL bBDT;
    BOOL bSmoker;

    PATINFO()
    {
        memset(szDeviceInfo, 0, sizeof(szDeviceInfo));
        memset(szUserName, 0, sizeof(szUserName));
        memset(szTime, 0, sizeof(szTime));
        nID = 1;
        nGender = 1;
        nStandard = 2;
        nAge = 20;
        nHeight = 160;
        nWeight = 50;
        bBDT = FALSE;
        bSmoker = FALSE;
    };
}PATINFO;

typedef struct PARAMINFO
{
    float fFVC;
    float fFEV1;
    float fPEF;
    float fFEV1Per;//FEV1/FVC
    float fFEF25;
    float fFEF50;
    float fFEF75;
    float fFEF2575;
    float fFET;
    float fEVOL;
    float fEOTV;
    float fPEFT;

    PARAMINFO()
    {
        fFVC = 0.0;
        fFEV1 = 0.0;
        fPEF = 0.0;
        fFEV1Per = 0.0;
        fFEF25 = 0.0;
        fFEF50 = 0.0;
        fFEF75 = 0.0;
        fFEF2575 = 0.0;    
        fFET = 0.0f;
        fEVOL = 0.0f;
        fEOTV = 0.0f;
        fPEFT = 0.0f;
    };
}PARAMINFO;
```

**EDIT2:** the C handler OnReceiveOneCase is the following:

```
 void CWaitDlg::OnReceiveOneCase(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PATINFO *pPatientInfo = reinterpret_cast<PATINFO *>(wParam);
    PARAMINFO *pParamInfo = reinterpret_cast<PARAMINFO *>(lParam);
    int nListCount = 0;
    CString strNo("\0");
    CString strFVC("\0");

    strNo.Format("%d", pPatientInfo->nID);
    strFVC.Format("%.2f", pParamInfo->fFVC);

    nListCount = m_UploadList.GetItemCount();
    m_UploadList.InsertItem(nListCount, strNo);
    m_UploadList.SetItemText(nListCount, 1, pPatientInfo->szTime);
    m_UploadList.SetItemText(nListCount, 2, strFVC);

    ++m_nCaseCount;
    delete pPatientInfo;
    delete pParamInfo;
}
```

Comment: Are the structures sent by the DLL packed? You may need to check the struct alignment.

Comment: Can you show the C++ structure definitions as well definition

Comment: @S.Monteleone Could you please clarify what do you mean by "packed"?  I have edited the response to include the C definitions of the structures so that someone can check the alignment. Note that the first time the callback runs, both structures are filled with correct data, I've checked against the C demo application.

Comment: @PaulF: please check the edited question.

Comment: @ManosGeorgoudakis Thanks for the update. So unless you have a `#pragma pack(1)` in your C++ code, before the struct declaration, the structs are aligned according to the compiler default, which may differ from the code on the .NET side. Apart from that, you have an access violation at address *0*, and that is an unmanaged error (not under the control of the CLR)... so you basically have a NULL pointer somewhere in the C++ code. Does the demo C++ handle that WM_RECEIVEONECASE message it sends in the callback?

Comment: @S.Monteleone: Yes, it does, I have included it under EDIT2. Thank you for the help, btw.

Comment: @ManosGeorgoudakis Thanks for the edit. The only thing that comes to mind is that the calling convention of the callback may be wrong, but we should see the DLL code to be 100% sure. Have you tried changing the declaration of the callback delegate from Cdecl to StdCall ?

Comment: Packing your structs isn't a good idea. No idea why that was suggested. You have not been getting good advice in these comments. The question is too long and complex for anyone to really want to engage. You should cut it down to a [mcve]. Help to see the wood from the trees.